# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Data' not found in /public_html/includes/src/Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Admin.php

Tags: magento-1.8

After unsuccessfully tried to compile the magento site I am getting the above error.

Any help in resolving this issue is highly appreciable

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check the Adminhtml directory in "/public_html/app/code/core/Mage" path.

May be by mistake the directory has been removed by anyone.